# how to send message to kafka producer using pipelindb?

Tags: pipelinedb

I am learning kafka and pipelinedb and I got across the following statements,
how to send message to kafka producer using pipelindb?
Do you have a example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Additionally, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Read our [SQL on Kafka](https://www.pipelinedb.com/blog/sql-on-kafka) post for a detailed walkthrough of how to use Kafka with PipelineDB. You can also read up on our Kafka integration in our [technical docs](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/integrations.html?highlight=kafka#apache-kafka).